# Read from string oracle

Tags: oracle, string

I have the following in my string "1406984110015" what I would like is to get;

```
str1 = 14 
str2 = 06
str3 = 84
```

I am creating a function in ORACLE that would in this case return 14.06.84

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SUBSTR:
[SUBSTR Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm)

```
str1:=SUBSTR(source_string, 1, 2);
str2:=SUBSTR(source_string,3,2);
str3:=SUBSTR(source_string,5,2);
```

(This assumes of course that you want three sets of two characters, as your example showed.)